# Java cannot find S3 service

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

I've got a problem following [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VbmA1F7a-0&list=PLSVW22jAG8pC-4yRGXgbuSIhvaohXSDPw&index=3&ab_channel=ProgrammingTechie)
Have been looking for solutions, but no result

IntelliJ can't read imports from package amazonaws services S3, when I build an app, the error says
[image: com.amazonaws.services.s3 does not exist]

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>youtube</artifactId>
        <groupId>pl.marcin</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

class which is connected with error

```
package pl.marcin.youtube.service;


import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class S3Service implements FileService {

    public static final String YOUTUBE_DEMO = "youtube-mw";

    private final AmazonS3Client awsS3Client;

    @Override
    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {

        var filenameExtension = StringUtils.getFilenameExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
        var key = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "." + filenameExtension;

        var metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());
        metadata.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        try {
            awsS3Client.putObject(YOUTUBE_DEMO, key, file.getInputStream(), metadata);
        } catch (IOException ex){
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    "An exception occured while uploading a file");
        }
        awsS3Client.setObjectAcl(YOUTUBE_DEMO, key, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        return awsS3Client.getResourceUrl(YOUTUBE_DEMO, key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include error text, not an image.

Comment: I am the author of the tutorial, I think may be the maven dependency - spring-cloud-aws-context or spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure is not downloaded properly.

Try to run 'mvn clean compile' to force maven to download the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a Spring App that works with Amazon S3, refer to this AWS tutorial. It walks you through building a Java Spring BOOT app that uses Amazon S3, Amazon Rekognition, and other services. It also uses AWS SDK for Java V2 - which is the recommended SDK to use.

The use case for this app is it analyzes many nature images that are located in an Amazon S3 bucket.

[Detect objects in images with Amazon Rekognition using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/example_cross_RekognitionPhotoAnalyzer_section.html)

There is also a sample Spring BOOT app that streams videos located in an Amazon S3 bucket:

[image]

Which seems to be what you are trying to do. See

[Building a Spring Boot web application that Streams Amazon S3 content over HTTP](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/create_spring_stream_app)